# Text File in UTF-8 Encoding format fails to convert into XML

Tags: xml, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, ansi

Would like to seek advise on how to manage the text file(with fixed length data positioning) which has Encoding UTF-8 format to convert into XML file. 
Basically the program fails to convert the Text File to XML because of non-ascii/symbol characters found in some data elements when the encoding was manually changed to ANSI. In effect, those characters impacting the fixed length position of the elements which resulted to the failure of XML file conversion. The source of data is coming from a free text field in SAP application and it was being extracted by the middleware application and sent as EDI file.

See below screenshots for reference.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You talk about a failure to generate an XML file, but give no details about how you attempt the format conversion whatsoever. Your screenshots only illustrate how you produce mojibake by using the wrong codec to decode. Please show the code for producing XML and more details about how this process fails (errors, wrong output...).

Comment: ANSI is a filter which will drop characters.  UTF-8 the only character I know that get dropped is 0x80.